# Creating a python library: how to write __init__.py

Tags: python

I have written a small Python library, currently hosted at [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/romanrdgz/pygpstools). As you can see, the library is called `pygpstools`, and it's made from 5 files:

- `gpstime.py` → A class
- `satellite.py` → A class
- `geodesy.py` → A module with some geodesy methods
- `almanacs.py` → A module with some almanac methods
- `constants.py` → Some constants

I want to use it as written at the README. For example:

```
from pygpstools import GPSTime
GPSTime(wn=1751, tow=314880)
```

or:

```
import pygpstools
pygpstools.GPSTime(wn=1751, tow=314880)
```

But after installing my library with command `python setup.py install` I'm getting `ImportError` when trying to access `GPSTime` class like this.

I guess the problem is at the `__init__.py` file. When I asked about this at the python IRC channel, I was told that leaving it empty does the trick. But I have researched and it looks like that only tells Python that it is a module, but it is not enough to allow this kind of importing I'm looking for, as at any other library out there.

So I have tried (not currently updated at bitbucket) to use this as `__init__.py`:

```
__title__ = 'pygpstools'
__version__ = '0.1.1'
__author__ = 'Roman Rodriguez'
__license__ = 'MIT'
__copyright__ = 'Copyright 2013 Roman Rodriguez'


import almanacs
import constants
import geodesy
import gpstime
import satellite
```

but still doesn't work: `ImportError` for `GPSTime`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Those are *relative* imports. They wont work in python3, and whenever you use the library with a different working directory. Use `from . import almanacs` to fix this.

Comment: @Bakuriu does that also work in python2.7? Anyway I have tried at 2.7 and I'm having the same ImportError when trying to use "from pygpstools import GPSTime"

Comment: I misunderstood which error you got. I thought the error was caused when importing the `gpstime` *module*, not the `GPSTime` class. To do that use: `from .gsptime import *` in the `__init__.py`, or `from .gsptime import GSPTime`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GPSTime`, for example, is in the module `gpstime`, so its actual (relative) name is `gpstime.GPSTime`. So when you import `gpstime` in your `__init__` you are actually making available the name `gpstime` which holds a reference to your type as `gpstime.GPSTime`.

So you would have to use `from pygpstools import gpstime` and then `gpstime.GPSTime` as the type name.

Obviously this is not what you want, so instead, you want to “collect” all your types in the `__init__` module. You can do that by just making them available directly:

```
from almanacs import *
from constants import *
from geodesy import *
from gpstime import GPSTime
from satellite import *
```

I have used `*` now to import anything because I didn’t take a closer look at what actual types there are in your files. You should specify it though. It is also recommended, to define an `__all__` list in your `__init__` so that you can control which names are imported when writing `from pygpstools import *`.